# angular 6 httpclient pass credentials in url

Tags: angular, authentication, couchdb, httpclient, angular6

I tried to make a HTTP GET request from a angular 6 project to a `CouchDB` by passing the credentials in the URL. But I always get an 401 Error "You are not authorized to access this db.".

Here the code:

```
var url = "http://user:password@localhost:1234/mydatabase";
 this.http.get(url)
          .subscribe(
              data => console.log(data),
              error => console.log(error)
          );
```

I also tried it with `{'withCredentials': true}` option but got the same error.

Angular Version: 6.1.0, using HttpClient

Comment: `Interceptors` would help you.

Comment: Which request fails exactly? The OPTIONS one for cors, or the actal get request?

Comment: @David: all of the requests fails because angular http does not pass the username and password, if I check the network request in chrome, it's only http://localhost:1234/... instead of http://user:password@localhost:1234/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. From memory, you cannot use username:password with HttpClient

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders(
{
     'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
});

var url = "http://localhost:1234/mydatabase";
 this.http.get(url, {headers})
      .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.log(error)
      );
```